# c++ programming with linux

Tags: c++

i am receiving a buffer with float values like -157.571 91.223 -165.118 -59.975 0.953 0 0.474 0 0 0.953 0 0.474 0.474 0 5.361 0 0 0.474 0 5.361...but they are in characters...now i want to   retrieve one by one value and put it in a variable...can any one help me please...i have used memcpy but no use..if i am copying 8 bytes its taking as -157.571 with 8 values including '-' and '.'  .... is there any solution for this ..

Comment: C++ or C#? This question makes little sense.

Comment: Someone is terribly, terribly confused.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a value stored in a string of some kind and you want to retrieve a floating point value out of it. If that is the case, it depends on the language you're using. If you're using C++, you should use a `std::istringstream` to perform the conversion. If you're using C, (and/or the `cstdio` system from C++ instead of `iostream`), you should use `sscanf`. If you're using C#, you should be using `Double.TryParse`.

Comment: i have used sscanf but no use...can u send a simple example ..in c++

Comment: @bindu: What do you mean "but no use"? Post the code you're using and perhaps we can comment. Also fix your question so that you're referring to the correct language! If you want to get good answers to your question you have to write a good question in the first place. For example, you have "Linux" in your title even though that has absolutely nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: i am receiving data from matlab through socket in c++ code...i am receiving buf as -157.571 91.223 -165.118 -59.975 0.953 0 0.474 0 0 0.953 0 0.474 0.474 0 5.361 0 0 0.474 0 5.361..in c++...but they are strings....i want to retrieve one by one value

Comment: @bindu: Post your code and we'll comment. I'm not going to solve your problem for you.

Comment: i want to how to convert string or characters to float value so that i can access one by one value

Comment: recv(skt_acpt,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
        cout<<"After Receiving-TIME  == "<<SysTime.time<<":"<<SysTime.millitm<<endl;
        cout<<"RECEIVED FROM MATLAB-----> "<<buf<<endl;

Comment: @bindu: Post your failed attempt at using `sscanf`.

Comment: sscanf...ok then how to retrieve that values

Comment: @bindu: I'm not going to comment any further unless A. you fix your question, B. you at least make an attempt to solve it yourself using the information I've already given you, and C. have posted the code of your attempt in said question. We are here to help answer questions, not to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your *buffer of floats* is this *string*:

```
"-157.571 91.223 -165.118 -59.975 0.953 0 0.474 0 0 0.953 0 0.474 0.474 0 5.361 0 0 0.474 0 5.361"
```

your cleanest C++ approach is to load this into a `std::istringstream` and then use the stream to extract the *float* values.. i.e.

```
std::istringstream str(buffer);
```

now you can use the stream in operator to extract a float value, and repeat this until there are no more (hint: check the stream flags)

```
  str >> {float}; // then do something with {float}
```

Optionally you can push this extracted value in to a `std::vector` to give you the floats in the string. I've not written out the full code, just the pseudo to give you an idea...

Comment: {float} is meant to be replaced by a float-typed variable name before use, btw

Answer (score 0):

You've got a string that contains a number of floating point values separated by a space.

If You could use `strtof()` to convert them to `float` values one at a time.

`float strtof( const char *nptr, char **endptr);`

where `nptr` is the string that you wish to convert and `endptr` is a pointer to a char pointer.
endptr will contain the pointer to the last character that was converted, so can be used to walk through your string.

eg.

```
char *rawString;
char **walkPtr;
float convertedValue;

/* do something to collect the next series of floats */

/* and now do the conversions */
*walkPtr = rawString;
while( still_some_string_to_process )
{
    convertedValue = strtof( *walkPtr, walkPtr );

    // increment the pointer to skip over the delimiting space
    *walkPtr++;
}
```

Appropriate error checking should be applied to ensure you don't run off the end of the string, etc.